# Format MySQL datetime field as "hh:mm"

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM m3
WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR) AND mod(minute(time),1) = 0
ORDER BY id ASC ";
```

The output for this query is for example now: 18:30:34

Every minute there will be a new datetime, and I will select only the full (half) hours. So 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00 etc.

Now I want only select the hours and minutes without the seconds included.

So for example: 18:30.

How can I manage it to have it in this query?

Comment: Do you want to extract the hour from the `datetime` column, like extracting a substring of `18:30:34`?

Comment: yes, every minute there will be a new datetime, and I will select only the full (half) hours. So 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00 etc.

Comment: You should update your question to explain it, it wasn't clear that you wanted rows every half an hour.

Comment: I have this query for every half an hour: $sql = "SELECT * FROM m1 WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR) AND mod(minute(time),30) = 0   ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 16 ";

Comment: In my database I have the column 'datetime'. There you see this: 2015-03-30 19:30:35. Only what I need from this data, is the hour and minutes. So in this example it would be: 19:30

Comment: So you just need to format the `datetime` field? If this is the case the query is irrelevant. What is the type of the `datetime` column, if it's really a `datetime` it should display the date and the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i') ...`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: I need to adjust only my query what is given.

Comment: Yes, but what's the name of the time field ?

Comment: In my database I have the column 'datetime'. There you see this: 2015-03-30 19:30:35. Only what I need from this data, is the hour and minutes. So in this example it would be: 19:30

Comment: Hum, yes so what's the problem ? If you replace your `SELECT *` by my piece of query you should have only hours and minutes and if you want all  field with that add your `*`. Like `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i') etc...`

Comment: When I have this query still my output will be: HH:MM:SS?? --- $sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i') FROM m1 WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR) AND mod(minute(time),30) = 0 ORDER BY id ASC ";